# How to use getJSON with this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, getjson

I just got this chained select box working that uses JSON data to populate the options. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87xpB/5/). The data is hard-coded, but I want to load the data using the `$.getJSON()` method, but I can't get the code right. I think the suggest.json file is triggered, but something else seems to be causing the problem. Would anyone please show me how to fix the problem?

I got the The Drop down Box from [this site](http://koviko.net/tutorial/building-an-accessible-client-side-chained-selection-drop-down)

The original code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var s = '[{"Box1":"Africa","CODE":1,"ID":"A"},{"Box1":"Asia","CODE":2,"ID":"B"},{"Box1":"South America","Code":3,"ID":"C"}]';


var jsonData = $.parseJSON(s);

var $select = $('#mySelectID');
$(jsonData).each(function (index, o) {    
    var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.CODE).text(o.Box1 + "|" + o.ID);
    $select.append($option);
});

jQuery("#mySelectID").dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":"|"});

</script>
```

Here's my failed attempt:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  $.getJSON('suggest.json', function(data){

  var $select = $('#mySelectID');

  $.each(data, function (index, o) {

  var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.CODE).text(o.Box1 + "|" + o.ID);
    $select.append($option);
  });

  });
  jQuery("#mySelectID").dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":"|"});
  </script>
```

Suggest.JSON:

```
[{"Box1":"Africa","CODE":1,"ID":"A"},{"Box1":"Asia","CODE":2,"ID":"B"},{"Box1":"South America","Code":3,"ID":"C"}]
```

Comment: are you going to get JSON from same domain or other ?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: @Evgeniy I'm getting the file from the same domain. And It seems to be triggered fine. Please hold on a minute. I'm setting up two examples, one having data hardcoded, one using the getJSON method.

Comment: @anurupr I set up two examples. Example:  **[original](http://painfulmouth.com/indexjq.php)** ||| **[getJSON Example](http://painfulmouth.com/indexjq2.php)** I don't see any error other than a warning in the original one (hardcoded) `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.` Other than that, it's working fine.

Comment: I tested your code, all work except jQuery("#mySelectID").dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":"|"}); Try jQuery("#mySelectID").show(); too see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you haved to call `$("#mySelectID").dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":"|"});` only when getJSON return you the data.

According to your code, just swap the plugin call :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('my.json', function(data){

        var $select = $('#mySelectID');

        $.each(data, function (index, o) {
            var $option = $("<option/>").attr("value", o.CODE).text(o.Box1 + "|" + o.ID);
            $select.append($option);
        });

        $("#mySelectID").dynamicDropdown({"delimiter":"|"});

    });
});
```

By the way, you have an error with your json : the last item (South America) have "Code" and note CODE" according to the others